# What is the difference between a generic type and a generic type definition?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection

I'm Studying up on .net reflection and am having a hard time figuring out the difference.

From what I understand, `List<T>` is a generic type definition. Does that mean that to .net reflection T is the generic type?

Specifically, I guess I'm looking for more background on the Type.IsGenericType and Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your example `List<T>` is a generic type definition.  `T` is called a generic type parameter.  When the type parameter is specified like in `List<string>` or `List<int>` or `List<double>` then you have a generic type.  You can see that by running some code like this...

```
public static void Main()
{
    var l = new List<string>();
    PrintTypeInformation(l.GetType());
    PrintTypeInformation(l.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition());
}

public static void PrintTypeInformation(Type t)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
    Console.WriteLine(t.IsGenericType);
    Console.WriteLine(t.IsGenericTypeDefinition);    
}
```

Which will print

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] //The Generic Type.
True //This is a generic type.
False //But it isn't a generic type definition because the type parameter is specified
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] //The Generic Type definition.
True //This is a generic type too.                               
True //And it's also a generic type definition.
```

Another way to get the generic type definition directly is `typeof(List<>)` or `typeof(Dictionary<,>)`.

Comment: Doesn't really explain the difference between Type.IsGenericType and Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition.

Answer (score 1):

This will help explain it maybe:

```
List<string> lstString = new List<string>();
List<int> lstInt = new List<int>();

if (lstString.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
    lstInt.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Same type definition.");
}

if (lstString.GetType() == lstInt.GetType())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Same type.");
}
```

If you run it you will get the first test to pass because both items are implementing the type `List<T>`.  The second test fails because `List<string>` is not the same as `List<int>`.  The generic type definition is comparing the original generic before `T` is defined.

The `IsGenericType` type is just checking if the generic `T` has been defined.  `IsGenericTypeDefinition` checks to see that the generic `T` has NOT been defined.  This is useful if you want to know if two objects have been defined from the same base generic type such as the first `List<T>` example.